# Bootstrap Carousel not working as it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i've been developping a website using bootstrap v4 but i have a problem with the carousel element as it's not working the way it should instead all the slides are showed and make a transition. you'll find as the end a sample where the problem is clearly visible
`enter code here`now my code is the following : https://jsfiddle.net/9b05o5g2/

and here you can see the problem clearly : http://t-w-g-org.stackstaging.com/

Comment: Your Fiddle seems to be working ok, isn't it?

Comment: that's the irony the fiddle IS working but if you enter the link i provided you'll see clearly that it's nit working there please it's driving me mad i need help

Comment: Well, it's hard to debug with that. However a quickfix could be to put `overflow: hidden;` on `.slider`.